# Fork() linux issue

Tags: linux, fork

Why program prints 4 times 'do' instead of just one 'do'?

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
printf(" do ");
if(fork()!=0) printf(" ma ");
if(fork()==0) printf(" to \n ");
else printf("\n");
}
```

Program prints
do ma
do
do ma to
do to

Comment: Edited, of course fork()

Answer (score 2):

You call fork twice in your "if" statements:

```
if(fork()!=0) printf(" ma ");
if(fork()==0) printf(" to \n ");
```

On the first fork, the parent A spawns a child B, then both the parent and child will invoke the fork a second time. The parent will spawn child C and the child will spawn child D. The result are 4 processes: A,B,C,D.

```
A ---- B
|      |
C      D
```

Since your prints are buffered until flushed to stdout and each forked process gets a copy of this buffer, four "do" are printed (check @ilkkachu answer).

If you intend to have a single "do", you should do this instead:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid > 0){
    printf(" do ");
    printf(" ma ");
} else {
    printf(" to \n");
}
```

Basically store the return of fork() in a variable instead of invoking fork twice in your "if" statements.

Answer (score 1):

Because standard output is line-buffered by default (or fully buffered, if you redirect it to a file or a pipe).

The first `printf` doesn't hit a newline, so it only adds the string `do` to a buffer internal to the C library. On the first `fork`, the whole process, including that buffer, is duplicated. Then one of the copies adds `ma` to its buffer, and both copies are duplicated (since *both* processes call `fork` again, not just the parent or the child.)

Finally, either `printf(" to \n ")` or `printf("\n")` is called, producing a newline, which triggers the actual writing of whatever was in the buffer.

You can either use [`fflush(stdout)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) to force the C library to output any buffered data before you fork, or use [`setbuf(stdout, NULL)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) to disable buffering completely.